# prevent columns with text from wrapping in Foundation App

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have 3 columns that I want to keep side-by-side. They work as expected with a short title. However, once I put text into the columns they end up one per row instead. How do I force the text to wrap so that the columns remain side-by-side?

```
<div class="grid-block align-center">

  <div class="grid-content">
    <p class="text-center">
      Less Stress
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
      Some very long text here.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content">
    <p class="text-center">
      Less Work
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
      Some very long text here.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content">
    <p class="text-center">
      More Profit
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
      Some very long text here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text wraps for me: http://codepen.io/colin-marshall/pen/mebqaX (I had to snag the css from one of their demo examples because there is no CDN for Foundation for Apps)

Comment: Thanks Colin. My code example is poor because it would need long text to cause the problem. I appreciate your reply though. I discovered the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the new Foundation App framework uses Flexbox, it still has a helper class using the more familiar 'medium-x' nomenclature. Therefore, the following code works, based on a 12-column grid which can be changed to any quantity of columns desired.

```
<div class="grid-block align-center">

  <div class="grid-content large-4">
    <h2 class="text-center">Less Stress</h2>
    <p class="text-center">
      Stop stressing about paperwork, monitoring xxx and xxx, tracking xxx and revenue, trying to stay on top of all operations. XXX takes all the stress away.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content large-4">
     <h2 class="text-center">Less Work</h2>
    <p class="text-center">
      Work less by getting rid of paperwork and streamlining your operations. Life's so much easier because XXX does all the work for you.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content large-4">
      <h2 class="text-center">More Profit</h2>
    <p class="text-center">
      Save money by eliminating paper and data-entry errors, and lowering operational costs. Increase revenue with more accurate billing, faster billing cycles and more time for customers. XXX makes you more profitable.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```